# Recursive Divide and Conquer Algorithm Modification

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion

So in my textbook there is this block of code to find the maximum element in an array by using the divide and conquer recursive algorithm:

```
Item max(Item a[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l == r) return a[1];
    int m = (l+r)/2;
    Item u = max(a, l, m);
    Item v = max(a, m+1, r);
    if (u > v) return u; else return v;
}
```

For one of the questions following the code, it asks me to modify that program so that I find the maximum element in an array by dividing an array of size N into one part of size `k = 2^((lgN)-1)` and another of size `N-k` (so that the size of at least one of the parts is a power of 2.

So I'm trying to solve that, and I just realized I wouldn't be able to do an exponent in code. How am I supposed to implement dividing one array into size `k = 2^((lgN)-1)`?

Comment: why do you need divide and conquer for this problem ? it is going to take same linear time as the original legacy solution

Comment: "I wouldn't be able to do an exponent in code" - why not?

Comment: I'm just following problem here though. I'm mostly just confused as to how to split it into the size k = 2^((lgN)-1). I know how to do simple exponents such as 2^5 but the lgN-1 part is messing me up

Comment: The first return: `return a[1];` is **wrong**! Should be `return a[l];` (or equivalent `return a[r];`).

Answer (score 0):

Both logs and exponentials can be computed using functions in the standard library.

But a simple solution would be to start at 1 and keep doubling until you reach a number bigger than desired. Going back one step then give you your answer.

(Of course the whole idea is mad - this algorithm is much more complex and slower than the obvious linear scan. But I'll assume there is some method in the madness.)

Comment: Thanks for the response.I know it probably isn't the most efficient but I think it's just to help us understand more about recursion. I'm still not quite sure about the code to split it into the size of k = 2^((lgN)-1) though

Comment: That's what my second paragraph is about. You're looking for the largest power of two less than N. Keep doubling till you get there.

Answer (score 0):

This finds maximum `k` being a power of 2 and less than the number of array items (so the array part is divided into two non-empty parts):

```
Item max(Item a[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l == r) return a[r];

    int s = r-l, k = 1;
    while (2*k <= s)
        k = 2*k;

    Item u = max(a, l, l+k-1);
    Item v = max(a, l+k, r);
    return u > v ? u : v;
}
```

However this is not necessarily the best possible choice. For example you might want to seek such `k` which is closest to the half of the array's length (for 10 items that would be k=4 instead of 8).
Or you may try to partition the array into two parts both with lengths being powers of 2 (if possible, for 10 items it would be 8+2)...